# SQL loses decimals after multiplication

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which includes:

```
COUNT    RISK
35       0.6456000000
11       0.5234000000
4        0.8431000000
```

I need a column to multiply the two columns. However I'm getting the result of:

```
TOTAL
35
11
4
```

COUNT - INT

RISK - VARCHAR

SQL is clearly rounding up the decimals as 1. I've tried casting as decimal, numeric and multiplying by 1.0. I need to retain the decimals for an actual calculation. Any help would be great

Comment: cast Count as decimal first...

Comment: Use `decimal(12, 10)` if you care about the number of decimal places.

Comment: What is the Columns' dataType (COUNT, RISK and TOTAL)?
Can you share the sql command you are running to multiply?

Comment: I echo the datatype statement of @RMH. If both Count and Risk start as decimals, they return a decimal as a result. Since Count appears to be an int, the total will be an int. I would also recommend changing the column name for Count. That's somewhat of a special word in SQL.

Comment: I'd love to see more info too. Perhaps it's unlikely at this point since there's already an accepted answer, but as jyao points out in his/her answer, it really seems like an explicit cast should be unnecessary.

Comment: I added the data types. I forgot to include those earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert result to decimal like this

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,10), COUNT * RISK) AS DecimalResult
FROM dbo.whatever;
```

Or convert COUNT to decimal

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT AS DECIMAL(16,10)) * RISK
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is really suspicious. From the surface, it seems the two columns [Count] and [Risk] have different data types with [Count] as integer and [Risk] as decimal or float.
According to BOL, decimal/float data type has higher precedence, I will quote the [BOL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309(v=sql.110).aspx) here

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence. If the conversion is not a supported implicit conversion, an error is returned. When both operand expressions have the same data type, the result of the operation has that data type

So to me, in **SQL Server**, when you do

```
Select [Total]=[Count]*[Risk] from [your_table]
```

You cannot get the result as shown in the original question.

Comment: I'm upvoting this despite it being more of a question than an answer because it's a really good question. I'd be very curious to see what the table structure and the query that produced the results in the OP look like.